# Overriding special methods on builtin types

Tags: python

Can magic methods be overridden outside of a class?
When I do something like this

```
def __int__(x):
    return x + 5

a = 5
print(int(a))
```

it prints '5' instead of '10'. Do I do something wrong or magic methods just can't be overridden outside of a class?

Comment: This seems to work: `def int(x): return x + 5`. Not recommended however..

Comment: @user2864740: There's an `__int__` special method. [Try it!](http://ideone.com/8DqvuN)

Comment: Documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__complex__).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer; not really.

You cannot arbitrarily change the behaviour of `int()` a builtin function (*which internally calls `__int__()`)  on arbitrary builtin types such as `int`(s).

You **can** however change the behaviour of custom objects like this:

**Example:**

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.value += other

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Foo(value={0:d})>".format(self.value)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> x = Foo(5)
>>> x + 5
>>> x
<Foo(value=10)>
```

This overrides two things here and implements two special methods:

- `__repr__()` which get called by `repr()`
- `__add__()` which get called by the `+` operator.

**Update:** As per the comments above; techincally you can redefine the builtin function `int`; Example:

```
def int(x):
    return x + 5

int(5)  # returns 10
```

*However* this is not recommended and does not change the overall behaviour of the object `x`.

**Update #2:** The reason you cannot change the behaviour of bultin types (*without modifying the underlying source or using [Cuthon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Cython/) or [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)*) is because builtin types in Python are not exposed or mutable to the user unlike [Homoiconic Languages](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HomoiconicLanguages) (*See: [Homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity)*). -- Even then I'm not really sure you can with Cython/ctypes; but the reason question is "Why do you want to do this?"

**Update #3:** See Python's documentation on [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__complex__) (*`object.__complex__` for example*).

Comment: why I can redefine int() function, but can't redefine __int__()?

Comment: @trollpidor: My answer explains why you can't redefine `__int__`—or, rather, why you _can_ redefine the ones that don't matter, but not the ones that do.

Comment: If you only care about one specific version of CPython, you probably _can_ mutate the `int` type using `ctypes.pythonapi` and a solid understanding of the C API and a willingness to debug segfaults. But it's actually a lot easier to just change the value of `5` into `10`. :)

Comment: I couldn't agree more :) Haha!

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure homoiconicity is the issue here. Common Lisp systems, emacs-lisp, etc. have different builtin-function and function types, but their function types are just data and can be manipulated without having to decompile and recompile and so on; does that mean they're not homoiconic? And if Lisp isn't homoiconic, what is?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if your AST can be represented as data and mutated your language is considered Homoiconic. So AFAIK LISP is. IT's also listed as an example language that is :)

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine a top-level `__int__` function, but nobody ever calls that.

As implied in the [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__complex__) documentation, when you write `int(x)`, that calls `x.__int__()`, not `__int__(x)`.

And even that isn't really true. First, `__int__` is a special method, meaning it's allowed to call `type(x).__int__(x)` rather than `x.__int__()`, but that doesn't matter here. Second, it's not required to call `__int__` unless you give it something that isn't already an `int` (and call it with the one-argument form). So, it could be as if it's was written like this:

```
def int(x, base=None):
    if base is not None:
        return do_basey_stuff(x, base)
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return x
    return type(x).__int__(x)
```

So, there is no way to change what `int(5)` will do… short of just shadowing the builtin `int` function with a different builtin/global/local function of the same name, of course.

But what if you wanted to, say, change `int(5.5)`? That's not an `int`, so it's going to call `float.__int__(5.5)`. So, all we have to do is monkeypatch that, right?

Well, yes, except that Python allows builtin types to be immutable, and most of the builtin types in CPython are. So, if you try it:

```
>>> _real_float_int = float.__int__
>>> def _float_int(self):
...     return _real_float_int(self) + 5
>>> _float_int(5.5)
10
>>> float.__int__ = _float_int
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'float'
```

However, if you're defining your *own* types, that's a different story:

```
>>> class MyFloat(float):
...     def __int__(self):
...         return super().__int__() + 5
>>> f = MyFloat(5.5)
>>> int(f)
10
```

Comment: So glad I was right about not being able to mutate builtin types :) (*their default behaviours that is*).